# Pop3 protocol error when using JavaMail to pull emails from oulook.com using oauth2

Tags: java, email, oauth-2.0, outlook, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to use JavaMail 1.6.2 to pull emails from outlook.com using a daemon service with POP3 and the new OAUTH2 integration.

I have successfully been able to authenticate using OAUTH2 and IMAPS, and I can pull emails using POP3s with plain authentication, so I think my OAUTH2 scopes, azure registered application, and client email have the correct settings.

The scopes for pulling emails that i'm using is below, and the returned token reflects that the POP scope is granted as well:

- `https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All offline_access`
- `https://outlook.office.com/POP.AccessAsUser.All`

The exception I see consistently is:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: Protocol error. Connection is closed. 10
        at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:215)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
```

Mail debug logs show this before the exception is thrown:

```
com.sun.mail.pop3.protocol               : +OK The Microsoft Exchange POP3 service is ready. [<long string is here>]
 CAPA
 +OK
 : TOP
 : UIDL
 : SASL PLAIN XOAUTH2
 : USER
 .
 authentication command trace suppressed
 authentication command failed
 QUIT
 <EOF>
```

My current code is here:

```
            properties.put("mail.store.protocol", "pop3s");
            properties.put("mail.pop3s.host", "outlook.office365.com");
            properties.put("mail.pop3s.port", "995");
            properties.put("mail.pop3s.ssl.enable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.pop3s.connectiontimeout", 5000);
            properties.put("mail.pop3s.timeout", 5000);
            properties.put("mail.pop3s.partialfetch", false);
            properties.put("mail.pop3s.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");

            properties.put("mail.pop3.sasl.enable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.sasl.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.auth.login.disable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.pop3.auth.plain.disable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.pop3s.auth.plain.disable", "true");
            properties.put("mail.debug", "true");

            Session session = Session.getInstance(properties);
            session.setDebug(true);

            Store store = session.getStore("pop3s");
            store.connect("outlook.office365.com", email, accessToken);
```

Some fields are likely excessive; I haven't whittled down what's relevant yet but this configuration works for IMAPS, and not POP3s.

I've also seen recommendations of re-adding the scopes to the the token request, but that has not worked for me as Microsoft considers it a bad request.

Any ideas for what could be going wrong? Or increased logging / capture to help?

Answer (score 1):

I actually had the same issue when I tried to use JakartaMail 2.0.1 and connect to outlook.office365.com by using POP3 XOAUTH2.

The "Protocol error" is caused by the Microsoft two line authentication issue which has been discussed in the github issue https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/issues/461

The related fix is in https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/mail/pull/477, I'm not sure whether this has been included in the latest JavaMail/JakartaMail release or not.

But I added

```
properties.put("mail.pop3s.auth.xoauth2.two.line.authentication.format", "true");
```

into my code, and I didn't see "Protocol error" any longer.

However, when I tried to connect with the access token, I got "-ERR Authentication failure: unknown user name or bad password." error.

I decoded the base64 format auth string and double-checked the username and access token, they were all correct. I have no idea what's wrong or whether there are additional settings needed for POP3 Oauth2 connection.

**Edit 1:**

Since I set the token scope for both IMAP and POP3, so I tried to use the exact same token with IMAP, everything worked fine.
I also used openSSL to do the same test and got the same result: Same access token works with IMAP but not POP3.

I would assume there are still some issues with Microsoft POP3 Oauth2 support, could anyone confirm this?

Comment: I can confirm it.  I have OAuth working for Gmail IMAP/POP/SMTP and Exchange IMAP/SMTP but POP does not work.

Comment: still improvements? i can connect to imap but pop3 fails.

Comment: using jakarta mail api 1.6.7 instead of recent oracle mail api 1.6.2 resolves ms office 365 xoauth2 pop3 problem

Answer (score 0):

Own answer since I cannot comment:

The two line authentication setting in the [answer by JeremyS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67590842/20301336) is needed by Outlook.

One other thing that is needed though is to allow POP in your Outlook account settings. Go to `Mail / Sync email / Pop and IMAP` and check if apps are allowed to use POP, which they are not by default. Without this you get the not very helpful "-ERR Authentication failure: unknown user name or bad password." error. Worked for me with Jakarta Mail 1.6.7.